# git - when doing git pull, I got message Fast-forward .gitignore and did nto get some part of the code base

Tags: git, git-pull

Yesterday, the developer I work with did some branch cloning to accomplish what he needed to accomplish, but when I did a git pull, the system pulled some items, and then I got a Fast-forward
 .gitignore on some of the files which seem to not have gotten added.

But when I did git pull origin master the system told me that the branch is already up to date.

Is there a way I can get the files that did not get pulled? And could someone please help me understand what is happening? Here is the message from the original pull:

```
remote: Counting objects: 33, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 20 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (20/20), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/genadinik/fundraising
   a49bd87..eef5124  master     -> origin/master
Updating a49bd87..eef5124
Fast-forward
 .gitignore                                            | 140 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 Crashlytics.framework/Versions/A/Crashlytics          | Bin 1893656 -> 1911576 bytes
 Crashlytics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Info.plist |  20 ++----------
 Crashlytics.framework/run                             | Bin 448880 -> 372912 bytes
 Fundraising/AppDelegate.m                             |   5 +++
 Fundraising/Fundraising-Info.plist                    |   2 +-
 Fundraising/en.lproj/MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard | 144 +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 7 files changed, 149 insertions(+), 162 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
```

Comment: "then I got a Fast-forward .gitignore on some of the files" -- I honestly have no idea what you are trying to say here. After "Fast-forward", you see a list of the changes. One of these changes is a newly added file ".gitignore".

Comment: @hvd oh, I thought it was a message from git :) ...but still I did not get those Crashalytics files in my system after that pull.

Comment: Ah, then blue112's answer looks good to me. You can also run `git status` to see if there are any other files that you should have but don't.

Comment: @hvd I just tried git staus, and it showed everything being in sync. But I still can not find those Crashalytics files, and my editor does not detect them either when compiling.

Comment: Just to make sure, you do mean those files that were listed in the git output, right? Which file, specifically, is missing? All three changed files in Crashlytics.framework are listed as modified, so the files should have existed already on your system before you pulled, and pulling should not have deleted them.

Comment: @hvd yes it is the weirdest thing. I had these files in the project before, but can not find them there now, and the system does not detect them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24896/discussion-between-genadinik-and-hvd)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please notice than .gitignore is a hidden file if you're on Linux or Mac. You can use ls -a to show it.

Then, if the file was accidentally erase, you can use, when you're at repository's root, the command :

```
git checkout HEAD .gitignore
```

To restore the .gitignore file the way it was at the lastest revision.
I can't help you more.

You should read twice what you're writing, some sentences doesn't make sense, too.

Comment: thank you - the issue I am running into is that some of the Crashalytics files in the message I got yesterday did not make it into my system. And I am just not sure why.

Comment: You can run `git checkout` on that file to have it appear too. You can use `git status` too to see your current working tree state. It has useful tips.